# How to remove from firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

getReference ("Posts"). child (postKey) .child ("date") where the date is written in "date" (which will be in the future, for example, April 30, 2020 in String format). I want to write a program that will take place "Post" to get the whole date, and if the current date and date from "Post" (currentDate == date ("Post")) then delete this post. How to get everything from the list for comparison?

[image]

I added the code where I add "Post". I get the date from calendarView so conveniently it is written in Russian language

```
private void deletePostFromFirebase(){
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = new Date();
    String newDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
    ref.orderByChild("date").equalTo(newDate).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                itemSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the date according to a condition, then you can do the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
ref.orderByChild("date").equalTo(date).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String key = ds.getKey();
            ref.child(key).child("date").removeValue();
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Perform a query `orderByChild("date").equalTo(date)` then you can iterate and retrieve the `key` and delete the child `date`.

Comment: If(currentDate == date from post){  remove(currentPost)}

Comment: orderByChild("date").equalTo(date)

Comment: Peter Haddad. Thank you!